# Csing for in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, loops, for-loop

Like a good programmer I guess I'm trying to be lazy and make the program make anything but I'm starting to think this can't be done this way so here it goes...

I have 27 variables a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,b1,b2,b3,etc,c1,c2,c3,etc...

I want the user to give me the numbers for each but I don't want to do it manually I want to do it with a for something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<=0;i++)
{
char a= 'a'+i;
char b= 'b'+i;
char c= 'c'+i;

printf("give me 1st number in square\n");
scanf("%d",a);
printf("give me 2nd number in square\n");
scanf("%d",b);
printf("give me 3rd number in square\n");
scanf("%d",c);

}
```

Any idea how to make this? if there's a way I would really appreciate you can tell me thank you very much XD

Yeah also if you can't understand or want me to explain better tell me and I will try my best to remake this.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for.

Comment: There are definitely better ways to do this...what do these numbers represent? You can use an array, or perhaps you need a `struct` that wraps values?

Comment: This for look weird to me `for(i=0;i<=0;i++)` O.o

Comment: BTW, `char a = 'a' + i` does not do what you think.  It defines the variable `a` with the *ith* letter after 'a'.  **It is not concatenation**

Comment: your `for` loop only runs once, I'm fairly sure you want `i<=27` and if you want the numbering to start at 1, `i=1`. But as other suggest, this code needs a lot of attention, variable naming, use an array etc etc.

Comment: yeah i know i was really doing a stupid thing XD totally forgot about arrays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what arrays are for. Instead of having variables like `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, etc., just have two arrays:

```
int a[5]; // a[0] through a[4]
int b[4]; // b[0] through b[3]
```

Then you can access the variables with expressions like `a[i]`, where `i` is any integer (provided you don't try to access outside the array bounds, of course).

Comment: haha yeah i totally forgot about that haha thank you very much

Comment: If you wanted to group them (a1, b1 and c1 all together), you could use `struct { int a, b, c; } data[5];` and access a member by `data[N].a` for aN.

Comment: haha yeah, I totally forgot about `std::vector` which relieves you of the pain of allocating arrays during run-time.